# Simple Python Program won't compile

Tags: python

I have a simple program that won't compile due to indentation errors. I believe I have indented it correctly. Can someone please explain to me why it won't compile on the line 5. its due to an indentation problem, but I believe I have indented it correctly

```
for n in range(2, 10):
     for x in range(2, n):
         if n % x == 0:
              print(n, 'equals', x, '*', n//x)
              print("compile please")
              break
     else:
         # loop fell through without finding a factor
         print(n, 'is a prime number')
```

Comment: When asking about Python problems, please post the *full* traceback.

Comment: What error is reported?

Comment: indentation MUST be 4 space and not 5 (some are 4 and some 5)

Comment: You have indentation problems. Some lines has 4 spaces, some has 5.

Comment: @Micheled'Amico It's not a *must* in the sense of compilation.. You can have 3..

Comment: @MarounMaroun you are right I would like to say that they must be all the same... sorry

Comment: Are you sure you haven't accidentally added a tab or something (which didn't appear in your paste)?

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: You can check for unwanted tabs by opening the python interpreter and typing `'\t' in open('putyourscriptnamehere.py').read()`.

Comment: To those that downvoted - I was a beginner python programmer and the problem had been frustrating me. I've been prevented from asking questions, could you kindly upvote the post so that I can get unbanned please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that your editor is probably mixing tabs and spaces. You don't want an editor like that.

Here is your code with no tabs, which runs perfectly fine for me:

```
for n in range(2, 10):
     for x in range(2, n):
         if n % x == 0:
              print(n, 'equals', x, '*', n//x)
              print("compile please")
              break
     else:
         # loop fell through without finding a factor
         print(n, 'is a prime number')
```

If you don't want to learn a new awesome editor like Vim or Emacs, then you could use something like IDLE. Or Sublime, Atom, Brackets, or really good editor.

Another really good way to make sure that you're indenting code properly is to type it into the Python REPL.